# VSC se cerró y eliminó todos mis archivos en la computadora

Tags: vscode

Alguien sabe como recuperar documentos eliminados del Mac con VSCode y que no tengan que ver con VSCode?

Contexto: Haciendo un proyecto, me tira error en la carga muchos archivos en procesamiento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El procedimiento aplicado fue: Ir al CONTROL DE CÓDIGO FUENTE -> ... -> Cambios -> Descartar todos los cambios.

Conclusión: El procedimiento eliminó todos los documentos de mi computadora.

¿Alguien sabe alguna solución para recuperar los archivos eliminados por VSCode?

Comment: Ese no fue un problema de VS Code. Hizo exactamente lo que le pediste: Descartar cambios. Si tenías cambios del tipo "nuevos archivos", al descartarlos, los eliminaste. Creo que unas clases de Git podrían ayudarte para evitar futuros problemas de este tipo, ruego y espero que no sea algo que tengas que entregar mañana o dentro de poco, tener más de 10mil archivos no es normal, quizás incluiste la carpeta de `node_modules`.

Comment: Gente, no le pongan negativo, es nuevo, tampoco ha leído cómo preguntar (https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ni tampoco ha realizado el recorrido (https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y tiene un escenario complicado para variar. Al menos dejen un comentario. Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: @fredyfx he cambiado el status de la votacion, no se haya sido. Saludos